# What creatures eat a humans life force?

Tags: mythical-creatures, folklore, monsters, demons

Are there any creatures that eat, or drain a human's life force? Have tried googling but am not sure which creatures do.

Answer (score 1):

"Life force" is a rather vague criterium. Many mythologies do not have this concept. The only ones I'm aware of outside of Abrahamic mythology are Eastern mythologies:

- [Prana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana) in Hinduism
- [Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi) in East-Asian Medicine, Martial Arts and Daoism

There are no myths about creatures consuming Prana or Qi.

**Judaism, Christianity & Islam: [Incubi & Succubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incubus)**
[image]

Said to eat the life force of those they seduce.
In some myth variations, incubi & succubi are said to eat the souls of those they seduce.

If you extend the scope to include various concepts of "soul", there are a few other ones:

**Ancient Egypt: [Ammit the devourer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammit)**
[image]

**Africa: [Soul Eater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_eater_(folklore))**
A soul eater is a folklore figure in the traditional belief systems of some African peoples, notably the Hausa people of Nigeria and Niger.

Comment: Your source does not describe the incubus or succubus as draining life force.  While this does occur in modern fantasy work, it is not found in the folklore.

Comment: https://mythology.wikia.org/wiki/Succubus "Succubi could suck the life force of men, leaving them exhausted or even killing them"

Comment: Then that site is inaccurate.

Comment: Then please provide some links to factual information that supports your claim, not just an opinion. SE doesn't work that way..

Comment: @Codosaur What's the source of that wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Succubus (female demon) and its equal male Incubus are two demons that come to mind that do exactly what you are asking.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succubus